# Best way to generate dynamic tests that don't leak using RSpec (LeakyConstantDeclaration issue)?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec3

Am taking over some Ruby code which includes a fairly large test suite. One thing that's been missing that I'm adding is `rubocop` to fix some problems. One thing I've noticed is that numerous tests have been set up to be dynamically generated in a way like so:

```
describe 'some test' do
  SOME_CONSTANT = { some hash }

  SOME_CONSTANT.each do |param1, param2|
    it 'does #{param1} and successfully checks #{param2} do
      # do something with #{param1} or #{param2}
      expect(param2).to eq "blahblah"
    end
  end
end
```

The issue here is `SOME_CONSTANT`. With `rubocop` this fails the `RSpec/LeakyConstantDeclaration` cop rule. The way these tests are set up these constants can re-assign a global constant by accident and result in random spec failures elsewhere if folks aren't paying attention.

The only workable solution to I've found is to change these constants into *instance* variables. For example:

```
describe 'some test' do
  @some_constant = { some hash }

  @some_constant.each do |param1, param2|
    it 'does #{param1} and successfully checks #{param2} do
      # do something with #{param1} or #{param2}
      expect(param2).to eq "blahblah"
    end
  end
end
```

There is a danger that these instance vars can leak into other it/example specs too (within the same spec file if a single test changes it), but at least it's limited to the individual `*_spec.rb` files, and won't impact global scope of the entire test suite. This also fixes the `RSpec/LeakyConstantDeclaration`.

Would anyone have any better suggestions? One that does not use instance variables, and is more modern RSpec friendly? I've tried using `let`, and `let!` but the way the tests are setup any variables set this way are only accessible within the `it` blocks. Have also tried using `stub_const` in a `before(:context)` block, but run into the same issue where the stubbed constant is only accessible within the `it`/`example` context. I also even tried `RSpec.Mocks.with_temporary_scope` and same issue. Instance variables seem to be the only thing that works in this set up.

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided feels a little too much like programming, rather than a test; e.g. I'd try to be a little bit more explicit rather than adding a loop of the behaviors.

Two constructs come to mind:

- Using the `let` (which I know you said you did), but with additional nesting. IIRC, you might be able to add another `describe` block outside of your `each` block
- [Shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/example-groups/shared-examples). This is what I'd try first. I added some pseudocode below

```
describe 'my test' do
  shared_examples 'does the thing' do |arg1, arg2|
    before { arg1.call }

    it "does #{arg1} and returns #{arg2}" do
      expect(arg2).to eq(true)
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like 'does the thing', Foo.new, bar
  it_behaves_like 'does the thing', Blarge.new, blah
end
```

You can also combine these with lets and/or a block (and refactor the shared example to reference these rather than passing in the arguments explicitly

```
it_behaves_like 'does the thing' do
  let(:method) { :foo }
  let(:result) { 42 }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree w/ Jay, I try to steer away from dynamic tests and prefer to make them simpler and explicit (if more repetitive). However that may be more of a refactor than you're looking to take on. To only address the issue of variable names I would consider not assigning the data to a variable at all e.g:

```
[:each, :attribute, :to, :test].each do |attr|
  it "does a thing with #{attr}"...
end
```

and if it's a larger array/hash:

```
{ 
  some 
  larger
  hash 
}.each do |param1, param2|
  it 'does #{param1} and successfully checks #{param2}' do
    # do something with #{param1} or #{param2}
    expect(param2).to eq "blahblah"
  end
end
```